# How can I use bootstrap's grid columns to set the width of X-Editable inputs?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I'm using [angular-xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/), the Angular flavor of [X-Editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/). I'm trying to adjust the input width using [Bootstrap's grid column classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes).

A similar question, [x-editable - adjusting the width of input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454589/x-editable-adjusting-the-width-of-input-field), offers solutions that change the width using custom styles/classes, but I want to incorporate Bootstrap's grid system.

### Bootstrap

> Wrap inputs in grid columns, or any custom parent element, to easily enforce desired widths.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

`col-xs-4` exists on the parent div, and not the input itself.

### X-editable

X-Editable renders a structure of form:

```
<a>hidden</a>
<form>
  <div>
    <input/>
  </div>
</form>
```

and applies custom styling to the input.

### Demo (JSFiddle)

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/10908/.

How can I incorporate Bootstrap's column grid widths with X-Editable?

Comment: inspect the live html and css rules that apply to each element. Will see most of the editable classes are display inline-block ... set to block. Keep adjusting right in the browser then update your css file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several gotchas that I ran into, but I managed to find a solution.

First, we cannot use `form-inline` with Bootstrap's column grid system. To remove this, we must override the form template in X-Editable. We also need to add a configurable way to apply the bootstrap column class.

```
yourAppName.run(function(editableOptions, editableThemes) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
  editableThemes.bs3.formTpl = '<form class="editable-wrap" role="form" ng-class="xformClass"></form>';
});
```

Because we removed `form-inline`, we cannot use X-Editable's built-in buttons. We can remove them by applying `buttons="no"` to the editable element.

Finally, we assign the form class in our controller (the caveat is that all inputs will have the same column count per scope):

```
$scope.xFormClass = "col-sm-12";
```

This gets us most of the way there, but there's some padding weirdness. This is because both the form and its parent have column classes. I hacked it out by adding the `row` class to the input's parent:

```
editableThemes.bs3.controlsTpl = '<div class="editable-controls form-group row" ng-class="{\'has-error\': $error}"></div>';
```

The updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/10933/. Hope this helps!

Comment: With your editable element `<a e-form="editForm"...>`, you can use `ng-click="editForm.$submit()"` to create a custom submit button.